# np.array() creates array of list-objects when given a multidimensional array, but should create 'normal' array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

something strange is happening when I try to transform a multidimensional list into a multidimensional array.
Here an example code how it should look like and what my goal is. This example works:

```
array = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
array = np.array(array)
print(array)
```

The output is as expected:

```
[[1 1]
 [2 2]]
```

**Now to my code that is going wrong and I don't know why.** I need the numpy arrays later for matplotlib. building_polygons is a multidimensional array. It contains a list of polygons where each polygon contains a list of points and every point consist of an x,y z coordinate.

```
all_poly_x = []
all_poly_y = []
all_poly_z = []
for polygon in building_polygons:
    poly_x = []
    poly_y = []
    poly_z = []
    for point in polygon:
        poly_x.append(point[0])
        poly_y.append(point[1])
        poly_z.append(point[2])
    poly_x.append(poly_x[0])  # closing polygon
    poly_y.append(poly_y[0])  # closing polygon
    poly_z.append(poly_z[0])  # closing polygon

    all_poly_x.append(poly_x)
    all_poly_y.append(poly_y)
    all_poly_z.append(poly_z)

all_poly_x = np.array(all_poly_x)
all_poly_y = np.array(all_poly_y)
all_poly_z = np.array(all_poly_z)
```

The error happens when executing the np.array(...) comand. Instead of creating an numpy array as shown in the working example, the following is created for example all x values(I shortened it):

```
[
 list([388426.87, 388433.48, 388447.84, 388426.87, 388426.87])
 list([388424.21, 388450.45, 388412.13, 388424.21, 388424.21])
 ...
 list([388457.11, 388430.84, 388469.1, 388457.11, 388457.11])
 list([388467.0, 388496.0, 388491.0, 388467.0, 388467.0])
]
```

**So why is it creating an numpy array with list objects?**

Comment: the lists differ in length

Comment: ahh damn, thats it thanks

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj sad, the list differ in length. Thats what confused me. I did not thought about that. Thanks for the awnser.